# What did Jacob Burckhardt intend to say by 'turn within' and 'turn without'?

Tags: middle-ages

Source: *[The Well-Educated Mind](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/039308096X)* (2 edn 2016), pp. 230-231.

> It is to Jacob Burckhardt that we owe the popular conception of the 
>   Renaissance as the time when man began to be modern. Burckhardt writes, "In the Middle Ages both sides of human consciousness—that 
>   which was **turned within** as that which was **turned without**—lay dreaming or half awake beneath a common veil. The veil was woven of faith, 
>   illusion, and childish prepossession, through which the world and history 
>   were seen clad in strange hues. Man was conscious of himself only as 
>   member of a race, people, party, family, or corporation—only through 
>   some general category. In Italy this veil first melted into air: an objective 
>   treatment and consideration of the State and of all the things in this world 
>   became possible. The subjective side at the same time asserted itself with 
>   corresponding emphasis: man became a spiritual individual, and recognized himself as such."<sup>25</sup>

<sup>25</sup> just references [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/014044534X).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is within the scope of history. I _think_ what the author is trying to say is merely that man needed to understand himself and his place in the universe.  Historical methods can be used to decode overly flowery prose, but i'm not sure that history is the best tool here; literature or poetry might be more appropriate.

Comment: This feels like it would be a better fit for EL&U.

Comment: @kimchilover. Looks like an answer to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construing your question narrowly, as asking what "turned within" and "turned without" mean, the answer is plain.  The first sentence of the passage in question is, in the original,

> Im Mittelalter lagen die beiden Seiten des Bewusstseins ---
>   nach der Welt hin und nach dem Innern des Menschen selbst ---
>   wie unter einem gemeinsmen Schleier träumend oder halbwach.

Google  Englishes it thus:

> In the Middle Ages, the two sides of consciousness lay ---
>   to the world and to the interior of man himself ---
>   as if dreaming under a common veil or half awake.

I would tinker, and say

> In the Middle ages, both aspects of human consciousness --- the outward looking one  facing the world, and the introspective one --- lay, in effect, under a veil, dreaming or half awake.

Both of which are close enough to the translation in your book.

The metaphor here is that consciousness is an eye, seeing either the outside world or one's inward nature. But a vile veil distorts what it sees, and (B goes on to say) the veil  was first lifted in Italy.

The larger question, of what Burkhardt meant, or whether he was right, or why he was sure he was right, or what a well-educated mind should make of all of this, is beyond my ken or care.